# Clicking on name in <ul> creates more <li> underneath names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem getting my little script to work correctly, and was just looking for a little guidance.  I'm trying to make it so that when I click on  a legislator's name, it will display more information about them, underneath their name.  Such as their party, and district.  However, when I click on a name, all it does is post more List-items underneath the legislators names.  I'm very new to programming and I'm sort of stuck on what to do here.  Any suggestions?  I'm using [Sunlight Congress API](http://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress/index.html) if that helps.

**Here's the HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Find your local legislators</h1>

    <form id="get-zip">
        <label for="zip">Enter your Zip code:</label>
        <input id="zip" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Look up</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="legislators"></ul>

</body>
```

**And the JavaScript**

```
    $(function(){
    $("form#get-zip").submit(function(){
        var zip = $("input#zip").val();
        $.get("http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?apikey=PUT-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE&zip=" + zip)
        .done(function(responseJSON){
            responseJSON.results.forEach(function(legislator){
                $("ul#legislators").append("<li>" + legislator.first_name + " " + legislator.last_name + " (" + legislator.chamber + ")</li>");
                $("ul#legislators").click(function(){
                    $("ul#legislators").append("<li>" + legislator.party + " " + legislator.district + "</li>").toggle();
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that when you create the li elements in your `forEach` loop you add all of each legislator's details, but put the part for which you want to toggle visibility in a separate child element. So the dynamically created li elements would look something like this:

```
<li>
    <p>Juanita Johansson (Senate)</p>
    <p class='details'>JavaScript Party Canberra</p>
</li>
```

And then add a `details` class to your stylesheet to hide the secondary details by default:

```
.details { display : none; }
```

Note that then the visibility is not the only thing you can then style separately for the details - you could also put them in a smaller font or whatever.

Then you can add a delegated click handler to the ul element that toggles based on that class:

```
$(function(){
    $("#legislators").on("click", "li", function(){
         $(this).find("p.details").toggle();
    });
    $("#get-zip").submit(function(){
        var zip = $("#zip").val();
        $.get("http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?apikey=PUT-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE&zip=" + zip)
        .done(function(responseJSON){
            responseJSON.results.forEach(function(legislator){
                $("#legislators").append(
                    "<li><p>" + legislator.first_name + " " + legislator.last_name +
                    " (" + legislator.chamber +
                    ")</p><p class='details'>" +legislator.party + " " +
                    legislator.district + "</p></li>"
                );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

A general note about the selectors you're using: if selecting by id you can just say `$("#idHere")`, there's no need to include the tagname first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. However, what I really want to do is not add legislators names in before typing in a zip code.  I want to type in a zip code, and it will then add the legislators inside the ul, and then you're able to click their names and it will show some more info underneath their names.  Sorry for the long winded response, but I'm still very new to programming.

Comment: Yes, my solution does what you want. The first part of my answer with the html was just to show the structure that will be created dynamically by the JS code. I guess I explained that poorly. Will edit. (Also I just noticed I put the click handler in the wrong place - I moved it out of the forEach, but intended to move it right out of the submit handler. Will fix that too.)